# Thermodynamics of supersymmetric black hole

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, supersymmetry

For a 4-dimenstional supersymmetric Kerr Newman black hole, we have

$$\beta\Omega=2\pi i$$,

and the index

$$\text{Tr}[(-)^Fe^{-\beta(M-Q)}]=e^{S+\beta\Omega J}$$

with $S+\beta\Omega J$ being $\beta$ independent.

My question is, how do we get the condition $\beta\Omega=2\pi i$? How to compute it for a general black hole? Also, how could we get $\text{Tr}[(-)^Fe^{-\beta(M-Q)}]=e^{S+\beta\Omega J}$? Specifically, I am working on AdS$_5$ black hole.

I am new to this subject, so it would also be helpful if there are some introductory review/textbook recommendation.

Comment: *with $S+\beta\Omega J$ being $\beta$ independent* Since $S+\beta\Omega J$ contains $\beta$, how is it “$\beta$ independent”? Is its derivative with respect to $\beta$ zero?

Comment: @Ghoster $S+\beta\Omega J$ is $\frac{\pi Q^2}{G}$